# How can I get saved model id in transaction Yii 1*?

Tags: php, yii

I try to get id in saved model in transaction, like

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try
{
    $someModel = new SomeModel(); // extends CActiveRecord
    $someModel->someProperty = '123';
    $someModel->save();

    $childModel = new ChildModel();
    $childModel->parent_id = $someModel->id; // this id is empty =(
    $childModel->save();
    // ... more some logic ... //
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $transaction->rollback();
}
$transaction->commit();
```

Why I can't to get incremented id in transaction?

Comment: you can set some_model table id is primary key and auto increment. you will get correct output.

Answer (score 3):

1) if you have `beforeSave` in your `model` then make sure it `returns` the `beforeSave` of it's parent:

```
return parent::beforeSave();
```

2) Try to save `ChildModel` only when `Parent` `Model` is `Saved`

```
    $someModel = new SomeModel(); // extends CActiveRecord
        $someModel->someProperty = '123';
        if($someModel->save()){

        $childModel = new ChildModel();
        $childModel->parent_id =  $someModel->getPrimaryKey();
        $childModel->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First model can't be saved due to some error but you not verify it so the second model doesn' have id of not saved model. Please use the following:

```
if ($someModel->save()) {
    $this->saveChildModel($someModel->id);
}
```

Also you need to make sure that someModel has valid configuration of primary key in database.